# Query a PL/JSON Oracle object and use it with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, pljson

Two questions about PL/JSON:

1. It is possible to create some index and query using JSON structure? Something like:

   select * from t1 where json_v = json('{"field_x": 23}');
2. I use [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) as ORM. How can I use json objects with Hibernate?

Comment: Maybe read the [Oracle json docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246).  Only supported in 12c.

Comment: I refer to https://github.com/pljson/pljson with Oracle 11g, that is the reason to use `pljson` tag, according with https://github.com/pljson/pljson/blob/master/doc/src/Index.md#getting-started: _You can also post questions on StackOverflow using the pljson tag._.

Answer (score 0):

*PL/JSON* is not integrated into the query engine as would be necessary for such as you are asking. Any question you have about Hibernate and JSON will need to be addressed to that community.